# How to use $transitions in angularjs?

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I want to make some changes when a particular route changes using $transitions.

Getting this:

```
Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: eventProvider <- event(…)
```

[Plunker link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5dVpXwQdAjwMXml9gPbX?p=preview)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [**`$transitions.onStart`**](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/feature-1.0/interfaces/transition.ihookregistry.html#onstart) definition on the documentation, it accepts 3 parameters.

> onStart(matchCriteria: IMatchCriteria, callback: IInjectable,
>   options?: any): Function

1st parameter takes matching criteria,

2nd takes `IInjectable`(can be service, factory, value, constant) or it can be function which accepts all dependencies.

Currently you had `event` in 2nd `function` which tries to get `event` dependency from app `$injector` & fails to retrieve it(as there is no such dependency defined with that name)

```
$transitions.onStart({
  to: 'caseStudy'
}, function($state, $transitions) { //injected dependency in function
  alert('test');
});
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/r25YyCOC1lhDZKHzUSCM?p=preview)

Comment: $transitions.onStart({
  to: 'caseStudy'
}, function($transition$) { //injected dependency in function
  alert('test');
});

Comment: tring to inject $transition$, it's not working in production code

Comment: You mean its working? I did tried in a plunkr, it didn't work.